# How to read(get) Y-Axis Scale Values from D3.js Chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

Is there any way to get the Y-Axis scale values from a D3.js chart.I have the following chart and I want to get the Y axis scales by clicking a button.

I want to read the scale on X axis which inside the red box.I have used the below codes to create the D3 chart.

Any ideas or input to get the values will be highly appreciated.

[image]

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'discreteBarChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 50,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){return d.label;},
                y: function(d){return d.value + (1e-10);},
                showValues: true,
                valueFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(',.4f')(d);
                },
                duration: 500,
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'X Axis'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                    axisLabelDistance: -10
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [
            {
                key: "Cumulative Return",
                values: [
                    {
                        "label" : "A" ,
                        "value" : 25
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "B" ,
                        "value" : 17
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "C" ,
                        "value" : 32
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "D" ,
                        "value" : 41
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "E" ,
                        "value" : 52
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "F" ,
                        "value" : 46
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "G" ,
                        "value" : 31
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "H" ,
                        "value" : 36
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-nvD3  Discrete Bar Chart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
    
    <br><a href="http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/" target="_blank" style="float: right;">See more</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe specific a custom Y axis formatter which just passes the default tick value out but also pushes it into an array for use later? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter

Answer (score 0):

You could select the ticks using d3.selectAll, and iterate on each to access the appended data value, For example, the following would work, and would need to be updated to ensure you are selecting correct class of elements in nvd3

```
let yValues = []

d3.select(".nv-y").selectAll(".tick")
    .each(function(d){
       yValues.push(d)
    }) 

console.log(yValues)
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea..but it is not displaying the values..maybe I typed wrong class.Could you update the above code with the class name I mentioned in the code?

Comment: In the code snippet you posted above, the y axis is contained within a g element with the classes "nv-y nv-wrap nvd3-svg", and within that, there are ticks with the class "tick". I would use ".nv-y" and ".tick" to select the elements you.  I've updated my answer